# Querying "where" clause with document auto-id firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently in a project using Firebase Cloud Firestore and VueJS.

I have this “where” clause, which needs the id of the selected collection. Basically it has to update, where the document id has the this.editSemId. There’s some other stuff to the method, but all I need is a way to get the document id from within my collection of semesters in firebase:

Here’s how it works:
http://recordit.co/Hu67ekLWHv

.collection(“semesters”)
.where(“DOCUMENT_ID”, “==”, this.editSemId)

I know how to “get” the document id, which is done with the “this.editSemId”, but I don’t know how to get it for the above query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [FieldPath.documentId()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#.documentId) to make queries involving the document id.

```
.collection("semesters").where(FieldPath.documentId(), "==", this.editSemId)
```

Comment: I might have an issue with my method:
https://pastebin.com/7mvZiq2F

I get an error:
ReferenceError: FieldPath is not defined
    at VueComponent.editSemester

Comment: I don't know vue.  You're going to have to figure out how to get a hold of FieldPath, maybe using its full name?

Comment: Adding:
import firebase from "firebase";
.where(firebase.FieldPath.documentid(),  <-- Tried with: documentId()

fixed the previous issue

Now the error is:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentId' of undefined
    at VueComponent.editSemester

Comment: @zetzah If I may intervene in the discussion, the full name seems to be `firebase.firestore.FieldPath`, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath#.documentId

Comment: @RenaudTarnec adding .firestore to it helped

I forgot to add doc(.ref).update to the statement as well, if any other users have the same issue in the future

I thank you both!

Comment: If you have any experience with Vuetify and adding a date in this case, where I have multiple v-models called date.

To give you an example:
http://recordit.co/2vQFRVKbOp

It creates a model for the date-picker for all of the items under "Erfaringer"

The code is: https://pastebin.com/k8mnTaxJ

So a function to just display one date-picker for the selected item

Comment: @zetzah I would suggest you create a new question for this Vuetify question and add the full code of your vue.js app